# Reading excel data from multiple related excel sheets and dumping in java classes

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, apache-poi

I have an excel file which contain multiple sheets. I want to relate these sheets with each other Ex. 
[image]

Here master is the root table, I will read the last column, if the names in it matches with the any tab name I will read the tab .[image]

and atlast I will dump the data in some java classes which will represent these excel sheets.
So when i will use the data in  code  it will be get by.  Master.Polygon.Cord etc.

Please suggest a way for it using POI .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of getSheetIndex(name) and getSheetAt(index) using the HSSFWorkbook class

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  if(workbook.getSheet(cell.toString())!=null){
        sheet=wb.getSheet(cell.toString());
        //code after getting the sheet
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave up too early. Whenever you are doing development the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/) is your best friend. You can always look at few examples. Its a straight forward task you just have to load the excel file and extract sheet by sheet and perform you task. You can also look on some tutorials for jxl they are very similar for beginners.